# How to change redirect after moving a page to trash?

Tags: pages, admin, redirect, trash

How could I change the redirect location after a user trashes a page? 
Right now they go to all pages here:....wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page

I want them to go here:......wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&page=custom_page_order

Answer (score 5):

Hook into `load-{screen_id}` and check if the `$_GET['trashed']` variable is 1 or above.

```
add_action('load-edit.php','wpse_trashed_redirect');
function wpse_trashed_redirect(){
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if('edit-page' == $screen->id){
        if( isset($_GET['trashed']) &&  intval($_GET['trashed']) >0){
            $redirect = add_query_arg(array('page'=>'custom_page_oder', 'trashed' => false, 'ids' => false ));
            wp_redirect($redirect);
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

This works - and I'm not aware of a better way of doing this...

Comment: I think this is close.
I get this url:/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&trashed=1&ids=112&page=custom_page_oder

It needs to be: wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&page=custom_page_order

Comment: I can't get it to remove the trash id from the URL? Any ideas?

Comment: I just edited the answer to make it remove ids and trash variable from the redirected url

Comment: If not obvious, if('edit-page' == $screen->id).. would change to   if('edit-book' == $screen->id) if 'book' is your custom post type